# Choose a type from a list

Tags: java, inheritance, enums

I have multiple classes that all inherit from the same `Block` class, and want to instantiate one of them based on a variable value.

Here is what I did for now:

```
public enum MapCases {
    FLOOR (Floor.class), // These are all subclass of my Block class
    WALL (Wall.class),
    ROCK (Rock.class);

    private Class<?> blockType;

    MapCases (Class<?> pointing) {
        this.block = pointing;
    }

    public Class<?> getType () {
        return this.blockType;
    }
};
```

Then later, I try to instantiate them given some data:

```
    private Block[] blocks; // Array of the mother type
    ...
    blocks = new Block[data.length]; // data is an int array
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        int choice = data[i];
        Class<?> blockType = MapCases.values()[choice].getType();
        blocks[i] = new blockType(); // blockType is of unresolved type
    }
```

But Eclipse shows me an error saying it can't resolve blockType to a type (which seems logical given the fact that java don't know yet the type).

How could I achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Try `? extends Block` everywhere you have `?`.

Comment: I didn't know these sort of things were possible. It doesn't work though, the type is still unresolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need reflection to do this. Consider this instead:

```
public enum MapCases {
    FLOOR {
        @Override
        public Block makeBlock() {
            return new Floor();
        }
    },
    WALL {
        @Override
        public Block makeBlock() {
            return new Wall();
        }
    },
    ROCK {
        @Override
        public Block makeBlock() {
            return new Rock();
        }
    };

    public abstract Block makeBlock();
}
```

In this case, the enum itself acts as the factory instead of the `Class` token it was holding.

---

Note that if you did want to stick with the `Class` token, it should be typed as `Class<? extends Block>`, as [Elliott Frisch points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055209/choose-a-type-from-a-list#comment31659166_21055209) in the comments. Then a call to `blockType.getConstructor().newInstance()`, which [GGrec's answer demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21055283/697449), will return an instance of `Block`.

Comment: Interesting. It seems to be the good way to go. I'll try that now

Comment: Was writing another answer with the same thing. Very nice and clean!

Answer (score 2):

Use reflection to create a new instance from the class blueprint.

Pattern:

```
Class.forName(className).getConstructor().newInstance();
```

Your case:

```
blocks[i] = blockType.getConstructor().newInstance();
```

Comment: It seems better but Eclipse still sees an error and tells me to wrap in a try catch that handles all sorts of instantiation exception. I assume it somehow needs a precise type, unlike what I did.

Comment: All reflection mechanism require checked exception handling. So it's okay to catch them.